Generate image of table with coloring without dataframe_image
i want to create an image (for example .png) of a table with 2 columns and 10 rows. I also define upper and lower limits - if the value in the specific cell is within the limits, the cell or text in cell should be green, otherwise red.
I had a solution using dataframe_image, but was not able to get my code running after creating an exe with pyinstaller. So now im looking for alternatives to dataframe_image
I found some possible approaches using matplotlib/pyplot, but they seem to be so complicated, i cant believe there is not an easy solution to this.

Please add test data (as text or as code) and the code you tried. Probably Seaborn's sns.heatmap() would be a good fit here.

I would use seaborn's heatmap (as suggested by @JohanC) to mockup a Styler-like table :
limits = 4, 8

between, otherwise = "lightcoral", "springgreen"
header, edges, text = "whitesmoke", "black", "black"

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(2, 4))

sns.heatmap(
    df.apply(lambda s: s.between(*limits))
    .astype(int)
    .reindex(range(-1, len(df)), fill_value=-1),
    annot=df.T.reset_index().T.to_numpy(),
    fmt="",
    cmap=ListedColormap([header, between, otherwise]),
    cbar=False,
    linewidths=2,
    linecolor=edges,
    annot_kws={"color": text},
    ax=ax,
)

_ = ax.set(xticks=[], yticks=[])

# uncomment to save a png
# plt.savefig("df_img.png", bbox_inches="tight", dpi=300)

NB: This assumes the index is irrelevant and index+columns names are unset.

Setup :
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap

df = pd.DataFrame(
    np.random.default_rng(0).integers(1, 10, (10, 2)),
    columns=["col1", "col2"]
)


This almost is what i was looking for. its buggy though, if all values are out of the limits, they all get painted green. I wasnt able to figure out yet why though as im not very familiar with lambda
